# Creating an action aggregation. Group by error

Tags: action, facebook-opengraph, aggregation

I'm trying to create an aggregation using Facebook's Open Graph for an action. Similar to how they have an aggregate for their "Cook" action in their Open Graph tutorials.
When I set up the aggregation and go to save changes, I get the error:

"No Paths Included
The Group By option for your aggregation must include at least one of the provided paths to your selected object type."

But it tells me under the advanced tab that "Grouping can't be configured for Aggregations that show actions".

So, any idea why I can't make an action aggregation, even when following their tutorial exactly?

Thanks, 
Gaz

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know, I opened a bug about his issue yesterday.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/182435155230238?browse=search_50c0c0f757ac57630521765

I'll update this post when/if the bug is resolved.

Comment: Excellent, I couldn't figure out where I might have gone wrong, so it's good to know that it is a bug.